# java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.api.ProcessorSupplier.get()" because this.processorSupplier is null

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I use Kafka Streams SDK 3.3.1 and pretty simple topology (that calculates overall number of messages) but got rather weird exception when creating topology:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.api.ProcessorSupplier.get()" because "this.processorSupplier" is null
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.graph.ProcessorParameters.toString(ProcessorParameters.java:133)
    at java.base/java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:4225)
    at java.base/java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:173)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.graph.BaseRepartitionNode.toString(BaseRepartitionNode.java:77)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.graph.OptimizableRepartitionNode.toString(OptimizableRepartitionNode.java:63)
```

My code to create topology:

```
private static Topology createTopology() {
    StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();
    KTable<Integer, Long> table = builder.stream("messages")
            .selectKey((key, value) -> 1)
            .groupByKey()
            .count();
    table.toStream().to("stats");
    return builder.build();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a bug that has already been fixed:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-14325

It should only affect you when calling `toString` on the topology. Please upgrade to 3.3.2 or, as a workaround, catch the exception around the code that calls `toString` (could be Kafka itself if DEBUG log level is enabled).